# Prove that $\frac{1}{P(2)N(2)}+\frac{1}{P(3)N(3)}+\frac{1}{P(4)N(4)}+...+\frac{1}{P(n)N(n)}=\frac{n-1}{2n+2}$

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

This was an RMO (India) question so I think there is something simple that I am not seeing here but I am literally unable to find how to even approach this problem. Here it goes:

For any positive integer $n>1$ let $P(n)$ denote the largest prime not exceeding $n$. Let $N(n)$ denote the next prime larger than $P(n)$. (For example $P(10)=7$ and $N(10)=11$, while $P(11)=11$ and $N(11)=13$.) If $n+1$ is a prime number, prove that the value of the sum
$$\frac{1}{P(2)N(2)}+\frac{1}{P(3)N(3)}+\frac{1}{P(4)N(4)}+...+\frac{1}{P(n)N(n)}=\frac{n-1}{2n+2}$$

Comment: Doesn't the right side simplify to $\frac{1}{2}$? Or is it a mistake in writing?

Comment: hint :  try with $n = 10$ and use that $ \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{m(m+k)} = \frac{k}{m(m+k)} = \frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{m+k}$  (and of course the prime numbers are not special here)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer for your question is found in question 4 in the following [link](http://www.isical.ac.in/~rmo/papers/rmo/rmo-2014-2.pdf).

Comment: The link says "Can't find the Server".

Comment: It is working properly. I just checked it out.

Comment: Nor for me (and many others).